# Is there an alternative way to track YouTube's API PlayerStateChange using Google Analytics Event Tracking?

Tags: iframe, youtube, google-analytics, youtube-api

I want to track video plays using Google Analytics without using the API script format, and instead track an embedded `<iframe>`. Is that option possible at all? Could an [enabledjsapi](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) in the embedded YouTube URL be possible, so it tracks the state changes whenever a video is clicked on?

Currently using this format to track player state changes in Google Analytics.

```
<div id="player"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var tag = document.createElement('script'); 
   tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api"; 
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
   firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player; 
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { 
   player = new YT.Player('player', { 
    height: '390', 
    width: '640', 
    videoId: 'fYmrMt01S1U', 
   events: { 
    'onReady': onPlayerReady, 
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange 
 } 
  }); 
   }
   function onPlayerReady(event) { 
   /// event.target.playVideo(); 
   }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) { 
   if (event.data ==YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) 
   {_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 
    player.getVideoUrl() ]); }
   if (event.data ==YT.PlayerState.PAUSED)
   {_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Paused',
    player.getVideoUrl() ]); } 
   if (event.data ==YT.PlayerState.ENDED) 
   {_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Watch to End', 
    player.getVideoUrl() ]); } } 
  // ]]>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post has a good description of how to track an iframe embedded youtube video in GA](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/10/22/automatically-track-youtube-videos-events-google-analytics/) 
I have used it to good effect a couple of times now.

Comment: Thanks! This seems the best solution for site wide implementation.